# Better way to go about constructing interactive map grid on webpage? Currently using a `table` element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, web-applications, grid

I'm looking to make a simple grid-map where users can click on a grid for information and zoom in/scroll around a large map, and most importantly be able to change the attributes (color etc) of a cell on user input.

I initially just created a `table` and looped through creating rows and cells, it works for a proof of concept but I don't think is ideal.

```
var COLUMNS = 300;
var ROWS = 300;

var table = document.getElementById('map');

for (var r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
   let row = table.insertRow(r);
    for (var c = 0; c < COLUMNS; c++) {

        let x = row.insertCell(c);
        x.innerHTML = ""
        x.id = c +':'+r;
    }
}
```

My other thought was maybe either just constructing a `<div>` for each cell and aligning them in a row `<div>` or maybe going another way and using `canvas` but that would require a total redraw instead of just updating a single cell. I don't have that much experience with designing UI's so input is appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition of "better"? Why is a table element not ideal?

Comment: if the user zooms in using the browsers zoom functionality, the cells do not seem to retain their aspect ratio. Also I believe `table` tags render a lot slower than `div` tags which is why most people create tables out of `div`'s so thats my next thought on best approach but I didn't know if I was missing something even better than `div`'s as you can see the max size is 300x300 which means rendering 90000 elements.

Comment: table tags render slower on which browser, on which platform, on which version of that browser. Such a statement is pretty meaningless, the next version of the browser could completely change things. You'd need to only create what you can see and use ajax to load on demand, otherwise the data (no matter how you render it) is likely to swamp the browser but only testing on all the platforms/browsers you want to support will really tell you that.